# How to repeat ring tone sound

Tags: android

I am using ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this,Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI); to get default ring tone and i am playing using  ringtone.play(); This is playing ring tone only once, i wanted to play until I call ringtone.stop(); 
i can see in log

```
12-10 18:37:40.968: DEBUG/Ringtone(2874): playing a tone with looping : false
```

is there any way to loop ?

following is my code,

```
ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this,Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
ringtone.play();
```

Comment: please @renjith provide the solution

Comment: @jyomin, I was trying this 2 years back, what I remember, on completion of playing ringtone I again called play().

Answer (score 0):

There is a loop flag that is embedded in the sound file itself. Maybe your default ringtone doesen't have it set.

Some more info here:

http://xanderx.com/2010/08/25/making-ringtones-loop-on-android/

Comment: Thanks Martin,I checked the link,I think it is possible by editing metadata of ring tone file, i didn't try this out. Because in my case, user may to keep default ring tone with built in loop enabled file. I have noticed  one more thing, for an incoming call the log shows this loop enabled. I was using same ring tone, I am checking with HTC wildfire phone.. 
12-11 11:41:57.232: DEBUG/Ringtone(174): playing a tone with looping : true